# Обновить dataGridView на Form1 при закрытии Form2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server

Нужно чтобы после закрытия формы dataGridView на главной форме обновляла данные, помогите пожалуйста.

> Получение данных из базы и вставка их в dataGridView

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Kod AS [Код кампании], Name AS [Название кампании], " +
            "ShortName AS [Краткое название кампании] FROM Company", conn);      
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

> Вызов второй формы для работы с данными таблицы Company

```
  private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Company Form2 = new Company();
        Form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

> Работа с таблицей и закрытие ее

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button_Press_Enter() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                int Kod = int.Parse(this.textBox1.Text);
                string Nazvanie = Convert.ToString(this.textBox2.Text);
                string KratkoeNazvanie = Convert.ToString(this.textBox3.Text);

                conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand myCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + "Company (Kod, Name, ShortName)" +
                    "VALUES (@Kod, @Name, @ShortName)";
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Kod", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                myCommand.Parameters["@Kod"].Value = Kod;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
                myCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Nazvanie;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ShortName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
                myCommand.Parameters["@ShortName"].Value = KratkoeNazvanie;

                int Uspex = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (Uspex != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Изменения внесены. ", "Изменениие записи. ");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Изменения не внесены. ", "Изменениие записи. ");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox3.Clear();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если особо не заморачиваться, то можно так:

```
  private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Company Form2 = new Company();
        Form2.ShowDialog();
        button1_Click(sender, e);
    }
```

Это сработает, только если форма открывается в диалоговом режиме. Иначе, код продолжит выполняться, не дожидаясь её закрытия.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Получилось!